# opencv python osx

Tags: python, macos, opencv, macports

**(Step 1)**

I'm trying to get openCV to run from python on my mac using the MacPorts install http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Mac_OS_X_OpenCV_Port, and also trying to follow [The Petite Geek's guide](http://thepetitegeek.blogspot.com/2009/09/installing-opencv-on-mac-os-x-with.html):

```
sudo port -v install opencv +python26
```

It runs for about 10 minutes without errors.

**(Step 2)**

I download [ctypes-opencv source and demo files](http://code.google.com/p/ctypes-opencv/downloads/list). I navigate to the `src` directory and run:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

I see like 50 lines almost all of the form: `copying ... -> ...`, which looks good to me. No errors here.

**(Step 3)**

I add `export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib` to the end of my `~/.profile`.

**(Step 4)**

I open a new terminal to test my install. From my home folder:

```
$ python

Python 2.6.2 (r262:71600, Apr 16 2009, 09:17:39) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Computer, Inc. build 5250)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cv
>>>
```

Does not work.

---

I read [somewhere](http://www.dudek.org/blog/150) that opencv installs python bindings with the default version of python for OSX, and I am probably running a non-default version, but this is not actionable information to me.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I struggled for a while with Python on Mac.  Here is how I finally (and easily!) installed it.  Remove all the things Python you have on there already.  They will probably be located at /Library/Frameworks/Python.Framework and /opt/local/var/macports/software/py26*

First download Python with Macports.

```
sudo port install python27
```

Then make sure your system is using this version with:

```
sudo port select --set python python27
```

Next install numpy with:

```
sudo port install py27-numpy
```

Now install opencv:

```
sudo port install opencv +python27
```

Now edit your ~/.bash_profile with:

```
sudo /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit ~/.bash_profile
```

or

```
open -t ~/.bash_profile
```

and add the line:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/opt/local/var/macports/software/opencv/2.2.0_0+python27/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

or where ever your version of the cv.so file is hidden....

Now restart terminal and try:

```
%python
>>>import cv
```

I'm using Netbeans for opencv and python and it works really nice.  Good luck.

Comment: Thank you!  After following several outdated installation posts from the internet, this is the one that finally worked!

Comment: The only guide that worked for me was this one, Had to say thanks ion a comment too

Answer (score 4):

```
$ brew search opencv
        homebrew/science/opencv
$ brew install homebrew/science/opencv
```

after installed, there is warning:

==> Caveats
If you need Python to find the installed site-packages:

mkdir -p ~/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages

echo '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages' > ~/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/homebrew.pth

so, just do

```
  mkdir -p ~/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
  echo '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages' > ~/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/homebrew.pth
```

Answer (score 2):

If you notice the first line output when running python, you'll see that you're still using the Apple-supplied Python interpreter. Try installing and using the python-select package in MacPorts and then try the instructions again starting from step 2.

Also make sure you followed all of the steps when installing MacPorts so that /usr/local/bin is on $PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Another "hack" I found during my struggles using CMake (but maybe the problem is the same with ports) : it appears that the python modules location has been duplicated on my Mac OS Lion, for a reason I can't explain.

CMake wants to put the "cv" module here :

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Whereas my default Python interpreter is looking here (thanks PyCharm for telling me) :

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

Moving both cv2.so and cv.py files to the second location, did the trick for me. I don't know if this is the cleanest way.

Hope it can help some googlers !