# How to properly install Python on OSX for use with OpenCV?

Tags: python, macos, opencv, homebrew

I spent the past couple of days trying to get opencv to work with my Python 2.7 install. I kept getting an error saying that opencv module was not found whenever I try "import cv".

I then decided to try installing opencv using Macports, but that didn't work.

Next, I tried Homebrew, but that didn't work either.

Eventually, I discovered I should modify the PYTHONPATH as such:
export PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/:$PYTHONPATH"

My problem is that I didn't find /usr/local/lib/python2.*...etc
The folder simply doesn't exist

So my question is this:
How do I properly install Python on OS X Snow Leopard for it to work with opencv?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 7):

I spent a couple days on this myself. For me, the problem was that that OpenCV installer was not finding the right python installation. It was defaulting to the MacOS-installed version despite the fact that I had upgraded python with homebrew and was using a virtualenv for python. I have collected most of my setup in a gist here: 
https://gist.github.com/4150916

Use homebrew to get all the dependencies, but then download the OpenCV tarball and compile yourself being sure to specify all the python related configuration options.

Assuming a virtualenv named 'opencv'...

```
cd OpenCV-2.4.3/
mkdir release
cd release
cmake -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=$WORKON_HOME/opencv/bin/python \
 -D PYTHON_PACKAGES_PATH=$WORKON_HOME/opencv/lib/python2.7/site-packages \
 -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON\
 -D PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers\
 -D PYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/libpython2.7.dylib\
..
make -j8
make install
```

Comment: I am trying this with OpenCV-2.4.6 and Python 2.7.4 and get this error with cmake: `CMake Error: The source directory "/Users/hdara/src/opencv-2.4.6/release/PYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/libpython2.7.dylib.." does not exist.`

Comment: OK, I found the issue, it was just a missing space before `..`. There were missing spaces that I added, but failed to notice this. The recipe seems to have the missing spaces.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the module using your python2.7 installation. Pointing your PYTHONPATH at stuff installed under 2.6 to run under 2.7 is a Bad Idea.

Depending on how you want to install it, do something like `python2.7 setup.py` or `easy_install-2.7 opencv` to install.

fwiw, on OS X the modules are usually installed under /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/ but you should almost never need to know where anything installed in your site packages is physically located; if Python can't find them without help you've installed them wrong.

Comment: I did try changing 2.6 to 2.7, but it didn't work because, as I said, the entire directory doesn't exist. I installed python from the .dmg image provided on the official Python website.

Comment: uh, yes. it wouldn't be in /usr/local/lib because it's in /System/Library/Frameworks/, but don't try to use it from where the system python installed it; install it again with the python you want.

Comment: After referring to a comment on this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846745/opencv-python-osx

I tried this:

sudo port install python27

then this:

sudo port select --set python python27

It didn't return any errors, but now I'm stuck on py27-numpy. Macports returns this error:
Unable to open port: tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open '/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/python/py27-numpy': No such file or directory

Any ideas? (thnx BTW)

Comment: Have you modified your shell `PATH` to include `/opt/local/bin` which is where MacPorts installs commands?  See https://trac.macports.org/wiki/InstallingMacPorts#a3.Settheshellenvironment For the numpy issue, make sure you clean the port and update to the latest versions: `sudo port clean py27-numpy; sudo port selfupdate; sudo port install py27-numpy`

Comment: After following the mentioned guide, opencv now works (even without numpy). I will give it one last try as you mentioned. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

#### Installing OpenCV with Homebrew

```
brew tap homebrew/homebrew-science
brew install opencv
```

#### Setting up Python

Depending on your install location - OS X Default

```
cd /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
```

or - Homebrew Python

```
cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7
```

Then create the symbolic link

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv.py cv.py
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so cv2.so
```

The above method sourced from a [blog post](https://jjyap.wordpress.com/2014/05/24/installing-opencv-2-4-9-on-mac-osx-with-python-support/).

Comment: in a perfect world only. opencv installation on mac is feisty by default.

Comment: I've had great results with brew and opencv installation as specified. You will need to link in the python bits.

Answer (score 1):

I searched and tried installing opencv3 with python3 for 3 days. Some links suggest for Brew and some virtual env, some say install xcode but all failed in my case.
Dont use linux steps to instal opencv-python on Mac. Problem with Mac is Python 2.7 is already installed by Mac. On top of that installing and linking all site-packages is little problematic and we end up with errors.

I'll share what I did: easy steps to install complete package opencv3, numpy, matplotlib, notebook, spyder etc.. on Mac.

1. Install anaconda, it creates a directory and install everything inside that
   use this link -> https://www.continuum.io/downloads
   download command-line-install
2. After download, goto terminal and download location of anaconda. 
   $ bash Anaconda3-4.3.0-MacOSX-x86_64.sh
3. Installation will ask you to append path to .bash_profile >> say yes
4. Goto home directory, run .bash_profile 
   $ source .bash_profile
5. check python, should be pointing to 
   $ which python
   $ /.../anaconda/bin/python
6. Last step
   $ pip install opencv-pyhton

$ python

$ import cv2

if no errors, we are good to go.