# openCV install Error using brew

Tags: python, macos, opencv

i am trying to install opencv on my MacbookPro OSX 10.6.8 (snow leopard)

and Xcode version is 3.2.6

and result of "which python" is

> Hong-Jun-Choiui-MacBook-Pro:~ teemo$ which python
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python

and i am suffering from this below..

> Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_contrib.dylib
>
> [ 57%] Built target opencv_contrib
>
> make: *** [all] Error 2

Full log is here link by "brew install -v opencv"
        54 248 246 33:7700/log.txt

any advice for me?

i just need opencv lib for python.

Comment: Perhaps look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128761/how-to-properly-install-python-on-osx-for-use-with-opencv/13574015#13574015) answer. It doesn't use Homebrew, but it should install OpenCV properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using macports it builds opencv including python bindings without any issue.

I have used this for osx 10.8.