# Install pyopencv inside virtualenv with --no-site-packages

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, scipy

I am trying to install pyopencv to virtualenv created with --no-site-packages option:

```
pip install pyopencv
```

But I am getting following error on Ubuntu 10.04.3:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:186 (find_package):

Could not find a configuration file for package OpenCV.
Set OpenCV_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file for

OpenCV.  The file will have one of the following names:
  OpenCVConfig.cmake
  opencv-config.cmake
```

I already installed numpy, scipy and OpenCV (libboost-dev libboost-python1.40.0 libboost-python1.40-dev cmake libcv4 libcv-dev libcvaux4 libcvaux-dev). Any ideas?

PS I know there is pre-built Ubuntu package python-opencv, but I don't know how to install it into virtualenv with --no-site-packages (probably symlink will work, but it is ugly...).

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: xamox, unfortunately no.

Comment: Okay well I will keep you posted if I can come across something.

Comment: @xamox and Vladimir - see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846745/opencv-python-osx

Comment: I actually ended up getting it working but I had to symlink the system opencv python .so files within the virtualenv.

Answer (score 2):

Adding this two lines to /etc/bash.bashrc (or just run in command prompt) fix problem.

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

Also follow insctuctions here: https://github.com/ingenuitas/SimpleCV#installation

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to install openCV before for building the python wrapper.

Comment: No. "--no-site-packages" says that env doesn't using any system-wide packages.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-opencv
```

will not actually install python-opencv, but it will install the non-Python packages pyopencv depends on.  I find apt-get build-dep an awesome complement to using pip within virtualenvs.

Answer (score 0):

Pip is missing opencv in your path.

If you have not installed opencv yet a `sudo apt-get install opencv` will fix this.

Answer (score 0):

```
here, try this, open /etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf as root with your favourite
editor say gedit and add this line to it /usr/local/lib
Reload configuration files created 
sudo ldconfig
now open /etc/bash.bashrc and add this line 
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH
then copy these files as below
sudo cp /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv.so /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv.so
And then try testing your openCV. HAPPY CODING
```

Comment: here's a complete solution script https://gist.github.com/olupotd/cd0c68f4c84153dffd16/download