# OpenCV installation doesn't work on Mac OSX 10.6.8

Tags: python, opencv, installation

I've installed OpenCV on my Mac OSX 10.6.8 twice. First using:

```
sudo port -v install opencv +python27
```

This seemed to install fine (no errors), so I fired up Python and tried to import it. Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work:

```
>>> import cv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cv
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cv2
```

I then tried installing it using [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6087778/1650012) (which everybody in the comments hails as "the final good answer!"). This also instructs on adding the following line to ~/.bash_profile:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/opt/local/var/macports/software/opencv/2.2.0_0+python27/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

So I just looked into this folder: `/opt/local/var/macports/software/opencv/`
In there however, I only see two files (and no folder by the name of `2.2.0_0+python27`):

```
opencv-2.4.4_3+python27.darwin_10.x86_64.tbz2
opencv-2.4.4_3.darwin_10.x86_64.tbz2
```

And from there I'm stuck.

Does anybody know why there is no such folder, or more importantly; does anybody know how I can install OpenCV on Mac OSX 10.6.8? All tips are welcome!

Comment: Which python are you firing up?  Try `/opt/local/bin/python2.7`.

Comment: @NedDeily - Python 2.7.3 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python (got that by running 'which python')

Comment: That's not going to work. That's a different Python. You need to use the MacPorts Python 2.7.

Comment: @NedDeily - Alright, and how can I do that? I already ran 'sudo port select --set python python27'

Comment: Like I said: `/opt/local/bin/python2.7`.  Or, better, adjust your shell `PATH` so that the MacPorts `bin` directory comes first (http://trac.macports.org/wiki/InstallingMacPorts#a3.Settheshellenvironment).

Comment: Ah, excuse me. Missed that in the first comment. Turns out my ~/.bash_profile was full of references to different python installs (Enthought, basic install, this macports one and I think another one). So I commented them all out and now it works like a charm. Thanks a lot!