# Mac Lion: Issue with opencv and python 2.7.5

Tags: python, opencv

I tried everything. Installation from source, via homebrew, macports - none of these options work for me. When I type in

```
import cv2
```

I get Segmentation fault in the best case scenario, but typically "no module named cv2" error. I followed all possible guides on stackoverflow from people with similar issues and still can't make it work. I have numpy and scipy installed and they are imported properly without any issues.

Could it be that python 2.7.5 (official) is not compatible with opencv at all? After two days of digging I am close to giving up on opencv at all.

Comment: The process given at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846745/opencv-python-osx?rq=1 seems to work. Have you given it a try?

Comment: the problem is - I need to use the official Python, not the macports

Comment: ended up installing via brew:

`brew install opencv`

then added `/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages` to my PYTHONPATH . Now `import cv2` works for me. Very stupid way to install.. Must be an easier way

Comment: If that worked for you, add it as an answer and accept it. Will be helpful to anyone who visits it in the future. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I configured it in the end for the official python 2.7.5 from http://www.python.org

First we need to install opencv via brew:

```
brew tap homebrew/science
brew install opencv
```

now add /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages to your PYTHONPATH . I did it by editing bash_profile:

```
open ~/.bash_profile
```

add this line in TextEditor:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
#Check the version in your directory
```

Save the file and do:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Now everything should be ready.